# Google action - duplicate MEDIA_FINISHED event received for each file

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

For each media response we are receiving duplicate MEDIA_FINISHED in MEDIA_STATUS. This is causing every user to skip one file for each media session. There is no identifier in the requests either so we can't ignore one of them.

This is for an existing Action SDK app which was earlier working fine and have broken recently.

This is my Response builder which has suggestion chips as well:

````
                .add(audioString)
                .add(
                    new MediaResponse()
                        .setMediaObjects(
                            new ArrayList<MediaObject>(
                                Arrays.asList(
                                    new MediaObject()
                                        .setName(mediaObject.getString("name"))
                                        .setDescription(audioString)
                                        .setContentUrl(
                                                mediaObject.getString("contentUrl"))
                                        .setIcon(
                                            new Image()
                                                .setUrl(
                                                    "https://www.somehost.com/blog/email-img/badge-108.png")
                                                .setAccessibilityText("Logo")))))
                        .setMediaType("AUDIO"))
                .addSuggestions(suggesstionArray);```
````

Answer (score 1):

We managed to implement a workaround by sending a timestamp in our state. Once Action sdk sent the duplicate MEDIA_FINISHED intent then we replayed the last audio again if MEDIA_FINISHED intent and state has timestamp which less than 10 seconds. It was still a bad experience but we had no response from Google so we had to eventually take workaround route

Eventually this was fixed by Google (Not sure if accidentally) last week and now we are not receiving duplicate MEDIA_FINISHED intent